# How to add an exist web form user control to a project ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

My partner has done a web form user control for me and I add it to my project.

But when add that to a page, the page does not recognize any component from the web form user control. It underlines every single component and say that component is not exist in the current page.

I tried to rename the namespace but it does not get better.

Any suggestion. Thanks so much!

This is the web form user control

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="GUIFORM_WebUserControl" %>
<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
        width: 638px;
        height: 161px;
    }
    .auto-style3 {
        width: 30px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    .auto-style4 {
        height: 23px;
    }
    .auto-style5 {
        width: 30px;
        height: 23px;
    }
    .auto-style6 {
        height: 23px;
    }
</style>
<table align="center" class="auto-style1">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4">List &#39;s Teacher</td>
        <td class="auto-style5"></td>
        <td class="auto-style6">List &#39;s Student</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView_ListTeacher" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="283px" OnRowCommand="GridView_ListTeacher_RowCommand">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="fullname" HeaderText="FULLNAME" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="USERNAME">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label_Username" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("username") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Current Supervised Students">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_CPStudent" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ACTION">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button_Select" runat="server" CommandArgument=<%#Eval("username") %> CommandName="select" Text="Select" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style3"></td>
        <td class="auto-style6">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView_ListStudent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="179px" Width="299px" OnRowCommand="GridView_ListStudent_RowCommand">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="fullname" HeaderText="FULLNAME" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="USERNAME" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ACTION">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button_Select" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("username") %>' CommandName="select" Text="Select" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4" colspan="3" align="center">
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Strikeout="False" ForeColor="#CC0000" Text="PREVIEW"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            Selected Supervisor:
            <asp:Label ID="Label_SelectedSupervisor" runat="server" Text="NaN" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView_Preview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView_Preview_RowCommand">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="fullname" HeaderText="FULLNAME" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="USERNAME">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("username") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ACTION">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button_Select" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("username") %>' CommandName="select" Text="Remove" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Label ID="Label_Error" runat="server" ForeColor="#CC0000"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button_Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure??')" OnClick="Button_Submit_Click" style="height: 26px" />
            <br />
            <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My friend might save this file in a different folder name with me.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="GUIFORM_WebUserControl" %>
```

I tried to create a new web form user control and it has this line

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="CMS.Components.WebUserControl" %>
```

So I changed the Inherits from "GUIFORM_WebUserControl" to "CMS.Components.WebUserControl"

But still error!

And this is the page I made to embed the web form user control

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="CMS.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Components/WebUserControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="WebUserControl" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <uc1:WebUserControl runat="server" id="WebUserControl" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Did you register the component in the page you are trying to use it in? please include the relevant lines of your code.

Comment: Post some code do we can see what you have tried

Comment: I have posted my code. please take a look.

Comment: Your user control  src is `~/Components/WebUserControl.ascx` but the file might be with name `WebUserControl1.ascx`. Try changing it.

Comment: It is still not working